# In "Never speak ill of friends", what part of speech is 'ill'?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Is *ill* here a noun, and thus the object of *speak*; is it an adjective, or an adverb modifying *speak*?

Answer (score 2):

It can be understood either as a noun or as an adverb.  Merriam-Webster lists this usage under both adverb and noun in its definition of [*ill*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ill):

> adv. 1 c :  so as to reflect unfavorably < spoke *ill* of the neighbors >
>
> noun 3:  something that reflects unfavorably < spoke no *ill* of him >

The Free Dictionary similarly shows it as both:

> noun 7. an unfavorable opinion or statement: *I can speak no ill of her.* ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ill))
>
> adverb 2. ill - unfavorably or with disapproval; "tried not to speak ill of the dead"; "thought badly of him for his lack of concern"

Comment: Yes; this can be understood as an old-fashioned transitive usage of 'speak'. [Speak] [ill] [of] = [Say] [something bad] [about]. Whether the 'transitive' analysis of such structures is all that helpful is another matter. The possibility of 'speak no ill of' surely disqualifies the adverb analysis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Certainly in the case of "no ill" it is a noun.  But as stated in the question, it can be either.

Comment: OP asks whether it can be; it does not state that it is. But after checking I agree: other examples (eg a non-transitivised usage, 'The right to speak ill' // the similar 'He spoke well of her') argue that the status of 'ill' here is indeterminate. // This sort of problem shows the advantage in treating 'speak ill of' say as a (transitivised) multi-word verb, a single lexeme, and not bothering to try to pin down 'ill' more precisely. However, grammarians have not agreed over the best way to analyse report quote and related structures.